# Download file from server using Laravel and Reactjs, getting empty PDF

Tags: reactjs, pdf, axios, pdf-generation

**Using axios to call the API to download pdf. I am able to download the file but there is no content**

```
await axios.post(URL,
         
          JSON.stringify({ filter }),
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: token,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            withCredentials: true
          }
      ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'expense.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution already! The issue was the content-type. I set it to blob and put it outside the header. Following code is working fine now.

```js
await axios.post(URL,
         
          JSON.stringify({ filter }),
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: token
            },
            responseType: 'blob',
            withCredentials: true
          }
      ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'expense.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
```